# Grabar resultado de una variable en un solo post

Tags: php

Se me plantea una duda, he realizado un pequeño y sencillo sistema de comentarios donde el usuario puede agregar un comentario con múltiples archivos adjuntos. Todo funciona a la perfección excepto cuando el usuario adjunta más de un fichero, el post se guarda en un TXT y se repite por cada archivo adjunto enviado. Lo que deseo es que todos los archivos adjuntos se graben en el mismo post pero no puedo lograrlo. ¿Podéis darme una idea o indicar donde cometo el error para tal caso?. Gracias de antemano!.

```
                  <?php
                  echo '<div class="widget wid-type">
                            <div class="heading"><h4>MENSAJES</h4></div>
                            <div class="content">';
                                $comentarios = "comments/comentarios.txt";
                                if (filesize($comentarios) > 0) {
                          echo "<div id='scrolldiv' style='width:100%; height:400px; overflow-y:scroll;'>";
                                // Muestra los comentarios
                                $archivo = "comments/comentarios.txt";
                                // Forzamos con nl2br que los saltos de linea "\n" los muestre en HTML
                                if (filesize($archivo) > 0) {
                                echo file_get_contents($archivo);
                                }
                          echo "</div>
                                <script>    
                                var scrollBaja = document.getElementById('scrolldiv');
                                if(scrollBaja.scrollHeight > scrollBaja.clientHeight) {
                                scrollBaja.scrollTop = scrollBaja.scrollHeight - scrollBaja.clientHeight;
                                }
                                </script>
                                <br>
                                <div class='text-right'>
                                    <a class='btn btn-default' role='button' onclick='scrollArriba()'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span></a>
                                    <a class='btn btn-default' role='button' onclick='scrollAbajo()'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span></a>
                                </div>";
                                } else {
                                echo "No hay mensajes disponibles.<br>"; // Si no existe ningún comentario no lo muestra
                                }

                          echo "<div class='review-form'>
                                <h6>envía tu mensaje:</h6>
                                    <form name='form' method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                                        <textarea name='desc' id='nombre' rows='5' class='form-control' placeholder=' Escribe aquí...' required></textarea>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='respuesta' id='respuesta'>
                                    <br>
                                    <h5 align='left' style='font-size:100%; margin-bottom:20px;' id='botonEnlace'><input type='radio' name='check' id='check' onchange='showContentEnlace(); showContentMultiple(); showContentBotonEnlace(); showContentBotonAdjuntos();'>
                                    Adjuntar botón con un enlace</h5>
                        
                                    <h5 align='left' id='botonAdjuntos' style='display:none; font-size:100%; margin-bottom:20px;'><input type='radio' onclick='location.reload(false);'>
                                    Adjuntar uno ó multiples archivos</h5>

                                    <div class='text-right'>
                                        <div id='enlace' style='display:none; background-color:#ECECEC; padding:15px;'>
                                        <h6 align='left'>Adjuntar botón con un enlace:</h6>
                                        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='url' value='' style='width:60%;' placeholder=' Agrega aquí el enlace'><br>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id='multiple' style='background-color:#ECECEC; padding:15px;'>
                                    <h6 align='left'>Adjuntar uno ó multiples archivos:</h6>
                                        <input type='file' name='adj[]' multiple><br>
                                    </div>
                                        <br><input class='btn btn-1' type='submit' name='submit' value='Publicar comentario'>
                                    </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>";


                                // Publica solo botón de enlace si llega una url
                                if (!empty($_POST['url'])) {
                                    $hora = date ("H:i");
                                    $fecha = date ("d/m/Y");
                                    $url = "<a href='" . $_POST['url'] . "' target='_blank' class='btn btn-default' style='margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;' role='button'>Enlace</a>";
                                    $fp = fopen("comments/comentarios.txt","a");
                                    fwrite($fp, "<div style='background-color:#F9F9F9; padding:30px;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>TEST" . '</b> ' . "el " . $fecha . " a las " . $hora . "h.<br>" . '<input type="checkbox" name="responder" value="<p style=\'color:#A7A7A7\'>Respuesta a <b>TEST' . '</b> el ' . $fecha . ' a las ' . $hora . 'h.<br>' . $_POST['desc'] . '<br>' . $url . '<br></p>" onClick="copiar()"> Responder<br>' . $_POST['respuesta'] . '' . $_POST['desc'] . '<br>' . $url . '<br>' . "</div><div style='background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:2px;'></div>" . PHP_EOL);
                                    fclose($fp);

                          echo '<script>window.location=document.referrer;</script>';
                                }

                            // Publica mensaje y archivos adjuntos, si llega una url, no publica el botón con la url
                            if (empty($_POST['desc']) || empty($_FILES['adj']['name']) || !empty($_POST['url'])) {
                            } else {
                            // Publica los archivos adjuntos renombrados
                                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                                $cuentaArchivos = count($_FILES['adj']['name']);
                                for($i=0;$i<$cuentaArchivos;$i++) {
                                    $nombreArchivo = $_FILES['adj']['name'][$i];
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['adj']['tmp_name'][$i],'comments/' . $nombreArchivo);

                                // Renombra el archivo con fecha y hora más número aleatorio
                                $codigoArchivo = mt_rand();
                                $fechaHora = date("dmYHis");

                                list($nombre,$ext) = explode(".", $nombreArchivo);
                                $renombrado = "$fechaHora-$codigoArchivo"."."."$ext";
                                rename("comments/$nombreArchivo","comments/$renombrado");

                                // Verifica si llega un archivo de imagen, audio, video o cualquier otro
                                if (!empty($_FILES['adj']['name'][0]) || !empty($_FILES['adj']['name'][1]) || !empty($_FILES['adj']['name'][2])) {
                                    $extension = end(explode(".", $ext));
                                    if ($extension == 'png') {
                                        $extension = "<a href='comments/$renombrado' target='_blank'><img src='comments/$renombrado' height='300' width='200' style='margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;' alt='Ver imagen'></a>";   
                                    } elseif ($extension == 'jpg') {
                                        $extension = "<a href='comments/$renombrado' target='_blank'><img src='comments/$renombrado' height='300' width='200' style='margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;' alt='Ver imagen'></a>";
                                    } elseif ($extension == 'gif') {
                                        $extension = "<a href='comments/$renombrado' target='_blank'><img src='comments/$renombrado' height='300' width='200' style='margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;' alt='Ver imagen'></a>";
                                    } elseif ($extension == 'mp3') {
                                        $extension = "<audio src='comments/$renombrado' width='300' height='200' style='margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;' controls></audio>";
                                    } elseif ($extension == 'mp4') {
                                        $extension = "<video src='comments/$renombrado' width='300' height='200' style='margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;' controls></video>";
                                } else {
                                    // Cualquier otro archivo
                                    $extension = "<a href='comments/$renombrado' target='_blank' class='btn btn-default' style='margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;' role='button'>Archivo $extension</a>";
                                    }
                                }

                                // Publica el mensaje, agrega url y archivos adjuntos si los hay
                                $hora = date ("H:i");
                                $fecha = date ("d/m/Y");
                                $fp = fopen("comments/comentarios.txt","a");
                                fwrite($fp, "<div style='background-color:#F9F9F9; padding:30px;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>" . $_SESSION['usuario'] . '</b> ' . "el " . $fecha . " a las " . $hora . "h.<br>" . '<input type="checkbox" name="responder" value="<p style=\'color:#A7A7A7\'>Respuesta a <b>' . $_SESSION['usuario'] . '</b> del ' . $fecha . ' a las ' . $hora . 'h.<br>' . $_POST['desc'] . '<br>' . $extension . '</p>" onClick="copiar()"> Responder<br>' . $_POST['respuesta'] . '' . $_POST['desc'] . '<br>' . $extension . '' . "</div><div style='background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:2px;'></div>" . PHP_EOL);
                                fclose($fp);

                          echo '<script>window.location=document.referrer;</script>';
                                }
                                }
                            }
                      echo '</div>
                        </div>';
                        ?>
```